# Command of start of.class of the file from command line

Tags: java, netbeans, linker-errors, bytecode

I created the project in `NetBeans` (according to the book P. Noutona, G. Shildta "Java2. The fullest management"), having specified as an `Example2` project name.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package example2;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
/*
 * Другой короткий пример.
 * Файл "Example2.java"
 */ 
public class Example2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int num; //объявляет переменную с именем num
        num=100; //присваивает num значение 100
        System.out.println("Значение num: "+num);
        num*=2;
        System.out.print("Удвоенное значение num: ");
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

In case of creation of the project the class example2.Example2 with the D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2 project folder (and project layout according to D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2) was created.  I created byte code by means of a command in command line

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2>javac Example2.java
```

therefore the Example2.class file was created. Further I tried to launch various methods.class the file from command line among which, for example, I was such:

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2>java example2.Example2
```

therefore received an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class example2.Example2
```

What command needs to be used and from what folder to launch?

Comment: @Jayan Your command didn't help. I receive the same error. I ask to specify also in the response from what path it is necessary to launch a command.

Comment: You need to change directory to D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src and then try it out

Comment: @ user1851132 : updated as answer

Answer (score 0):

**Change your java compile command**

To compile use
 javac -d . ClassName.java

to run java class file with package name use

java packageName/className
OR

java packageName.className

Comment: Your command didn't help. I receive the same error. I ask to specify also in the response from what path it is necessary to launch a command. @MohammodHossain

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies within the package names. The class you are compiling is inside the package example2 and is called Example2, therefor it's full path is example2.Example2. So far so good. The problem is how java will find the class. Java will transform the package declaration in the command into a file path, in this case example2/Example2.class. Since your class is placed at Example2.class and not at example2/Example2.class, it will not be found and cause an error. 
To fix this, create a subdirectory called example2 and place the class file in there.

Answer (score 0):

go to directory D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\
then type java -cp D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src example2.Example2

The main directory where all your class files will lie should be in classpath ( which is D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src in your case ). Alternatively you can set classpath using your windows Environment variables also. Once that is done; you can run any of your class file using

```
java <full qualified class name>
```

for example
java example2.Example2

Answer (score 0):

You are here

```
 D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2
```

When you compile

```
javac Example2.java
```

the classes will appear in 
    D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2

Try dir and list them

```
  Dir D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2
```

Now to run a class, it must be in the class path.  The lookup will add fully qualified name of class (with dot replaced with / ) and search in every path.  In your case

```
java -cp D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src example2.Example
```

should work.

The java program will look for example2/Example2.class under all classpaths you give. See more details at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compile your .java file to another folder, for xample to "build" as it is done usually?

When Netbeans compiles files automatically it creates the following structure:

```
"proj_dir"/src/"package"/"code".java
"proj_dir"/build/classes/"package"/"code".class
```

Try doing it like this, but manually. Then go to "build/classes" dir from command line and type:

```
  java "package"."code"
```

This is general way to run compiled java-code.

In your case it has to look like:

```
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2\Example2.java
D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\build\classes\example2>Example2.class
```

CMD commands to do it:

```
cd D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\src\example2
javac -d ..\..\build\classes Example2.java
cd D:\ExamplesFromBook\Example2\Example2\build\classes
java example2.Example2
```

It works with simple programs.